# Как при ромбовидном наследовании удалить метод базового класса в одной из веток так что бы он остался виден в конечном наследнике?

Tags: c++, наследование, c++17

Есть класс FooBase у которого есть метод FunBase(). От этого класса через виртуальное наследование наследуются два класса FooA и FooB. В FooB метод FunBase() удаляется т. к. его там по логике программы быть не может. От этих двух классов наследуется класс FooEnd в котором метод FunBase() должен быть. Как изменить код так что бы у объекта FooEnd стал возможен вызов метода FunBase() без использования агрегации.

```
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class FooBase {
 public:
   void FunBase() {
      cout << "FunBase" << endl;
   }
};

class FooA: virtual public FooBase {
 public:
   void FunA() {
      cout << "FunA" << endl;
   }
};

class FooB: virtual public FooBase {
 public:
   void FunB() {
      cout << "FunB" << endl;
   }
   void FunBase() = delete;

};

class FooEnd: public FooA, public FooB {
 public:
   void FunEnd() {
      cout << "FunEnd" << endl;
   }
};

int main() {
   FooEnd bat;
   bat.FunBase();
   return 0;
}
```

Под агрегациея я понимаю запись вида:

```
class FooEnd: public FooA, public FooB {
 public:
   void FunEnd() {
      cout << "FunEnd" << endl;
   }
   void FunBase() {
      FooBase::FunBase();
   };
};
```

Comment: Вот поясните мне, какое может быть наследование (т.е. отношение ЯВЛЯЕТСЯ), в котором не должно быть некоторой функциональности, которая есть в базовом классе? Вы уверены, что вам нужно наследование не просто потому, что вам нравится, как звучит этот термин?

Comment: @Harry да, на 100% уверен. Базовый класс тут содержит ресурсы и является виртуальным(извиняюсь что не отобразил это в примере). Его объект не может быть создан так что принцип Барбары Лисков сохраняется (хотя нет, не сохряняется если использовать указатель на FooBase -_-). При этом FunBase обязательно должен быть реализован в базовом классе потому что от него будет наследоваться ещё много кто. Если FunBase реализовывать выше по дереву наследование то получится множество его реализаций что неприемлемо(одно изменение в методе придётся дублировать везде).

Comment: @Harry Что бы было понятней давайте я попробую привести пример. На специфической платформе есть абстрактный порт в котором помимо интерфейса определены некоторые ресурсы и методы, которые едины для всех подобных портов на этой платформе. И есть три его реализации input порт который (является) портом. output порт который тоже является портом. И input\output порт который может работать в обоих режимах и (является) как входным так и выходным. Проблема в том что в выходном порте ненужны часть открытых методов абстрактного порта(например слушатель прерывания который обязан быть у каждого порта).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Можно сделать так:

```
class FooB: virtual public FooBase {
public:
    void FunB() {
        cout << "FunB" << endl;
    }
protected:
    using FooBase::FunBase;
};

class FooEnd: public FooA, public FooB {
public:
    void FunEnd() {
        cout << "FunEnd" << endl;
    }
    using FooBase::FunBase;
};
```

P.S. я считаю, что если появилось такое желание, то что-то не так в дизайне классов, поэтому рекомендую всё же подумать, как сделать это по-человечски.

Comment: Большое спасибо за ответ. Только я вместо вашего варианта сделал using FooBase::FunBase в классе FooEnd но суть осталась та же.

Comment: Самое полезное  это в  P.S.

Comment: Я вчера вечером и сегодня утром хорошо подумал. Вы и Harry правы. Я понял как нужно перестроить. Спасибо вам.